# How to plot data with gaps into subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with gaps

```
                                    temperature 
    data                                                        
    2016-01-01 01:00:00              -8.2 
    2016-01-01 02:00:00              -8.3  
    2016-01-01 03:00:00              -9.1 
    2016-01-01 04:00:00              -9.1  
    2016-01-01 05:00:00              -9.6 
        ...                           ...     
    2020-02-29 20:00:00               5.9   
    2020-02-29 21:00:00               5.4   
    2020-02-29 22:00:00               4.7 
    2020-02-29 23:00:00               4.3 
    2020-03-01 00:00:00               4.3
```

Here is the code for some sample data, different from mine but the concept is the same:

```
def tworzeniedaty():
    import pandas as pd
    rng1 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-02-29', freq='D'))
    rng2 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-12-15', end='2017-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng3 = list(pd.date_range(start='2017-12-15', end='2018-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng4 = list(pd.date_range(start='2018-12-15', end='2019-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng5 = list(pd.date_range(start='2019-12-15', end='2020-02-29', freq='D'))
    return rng1 + rng2 + rng3 + rng4 + rng5


import random
import pandas as pd

lista = [random.randrange(1, 10, 1) for i in range(len(tworzeniedaty()))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': tworzeniedaty(), 'temperature': lista})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

When I plot the data I get a very messy plot.
[image]

Instead I would like to get:

[image]

It is the same question as [How to plot only specific months in a time series of several years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999718/how-to-plot-only-specific-months-in-a-time-series-of-several-years) but I would like to do it in python and can't decipher R code.

Comment: Do you want subplots of groups of data or do you just want to get rid of the connecting lines in this graph? In both cases, you should define what a "group" or a "gap" is. Looking at the graph, it seems defining it as "no data for at least three months" is an acceptable gap definition. But does it hold true for all your data?

Comment: I want to do subplots, yes 3 months break holds for my data. I added some sample data, with dates matching mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group the data by calculating the difference between dates and checking if it exceeds a limit like three months:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import pandas as pd

def tworzeniedaty():
    rng1 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-02-29', freq='D'))
    rng2 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-12-15', end='2017-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng3 = list(pd.date_range(start='2017-12-15', end='2018-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng4 = list(pd.date_range(start='2018-12-15', end='2019-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng5 = list(pd.date_range(start='2019-12-15', end='2020-02-29', freq='D'))
    return rng1 + rng2 + rng3 + rng4 + rng5

lista = [random.randrange(1, 10, 1) for i in range(len(tworzeniedaty()))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': tworzeniedaty(), 'temperature': lista})


#assuming that the df is sorted by date, we look for gaps of more than 3 months
#then we label the groups with consecutive numbers
df["groups"] = (df["Date"].dt.month.diff() > 3).cumsum()
n = 1 + df["groups"].max()

#creating the desired number of subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, n, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=True)

#plotting each group into a subplot
for (i, group_df), ax in zip(df.groupby("groups"), axes.flat):
    ax.plot(group_df["Date"], group_df["temperature"])
      
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Obviously, some fine-tuning is necessary if more groups should exist. In this case, a grid would be appropriate - one can [create a subplot grid and remove unnecessary subplots like in this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-markevery-demo-py). The x-labels probably also need some adjustment with [a matplotlib Locator and Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141) for better appearance. Some of this can be automated using the grouping variable with [`hue` in seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html); however, this may lead to a different set of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The  best approach I think is to filter out Jun/Jul/Aug data, as done in the R code. This should help:

```
def tworzeniedaty():
    import pandas as pd
    rng1 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-02-29', freq='D'))
    rng2 = list(pd.date_range(start='2016-12-15', end='2017-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng3 = list(pd.date_range(start='2017-12-15', end='2018-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng4 = list(pd.date_range(start='2018-12-15', end='2019-02-28', freq='D'))
    rng5 = list(pd.date_range(start='2019-12-15', end='2020-02-29', freq='D'))
    return rng1 + rng2 + rng3 + rng4 + rng5


import random
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista = [random.randrange(1, 10, 1) for i in range(len(tworzeniedaty()))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': tworzeniedaty(), 'temperature': lista})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d")

years = list(set(df.Date.dt.year))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(years))
for i in years:
        df_set =  df[df.Date.dt.year == i]
        df_set.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
        df_set.index = df_set.index.map(str)
        ax[years.index(i)].plot(df_set)
        ax[years.index(i)].title.set_text(i)

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you show the data? I mean the code to create this sample dataframe, so that I can update the answer accordingly. @Mr.T. As per my understanding, this is how the data is supposed to be, comparing with the R solution attached with this question.

Comment: I added a sample data.

Comment: @wychen it is constant data there, and also the date there is in string and not datetime format.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check @wychen

Comment: But you just plot the data with continuous line, nothing like I want in my description.

Comment: If you want to replicate what is done in the R code exactly, we would need to do subplots instead of a single plot, I will try and update the code again to match what can be done.

Comment: Fixed, please check @wychen